# how to edit state and country list and update it using php

Tags: php

Hi i am storing countries and states in database i need to edit and update it in database but when i click on edit option iam not able to fetch the record from database.Here is my code.

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://lab.iamrohit.in/js/location.js"></script>
Country:<select name="country" class="countries" id="country" value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>">
                            <option >Select Country</option>
                            </select><br/>
                    State:<select name="state" class="states" id="state" value="<?php echo $row['state'];?>">
                    <option >Select State</option>
                    </select><br/>
```

If i click on console the value is printing but iam not able to display in frontend.Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Select boxes don't have a value attribute. You need to echo an option with that value, and then add `selected=selected` before closing the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this code.

```
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://lab.iamrohit.in/js/location.js"></script>
    Country:<select name="country" class="countries" id="country">
<option value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>"><?php echo $row['country'];?></option>
                                <option >Select Country</option>
                                </select><br/>
                        State:<select name="state" class="states" id="state">

<option value="<?php echo $row['state'];?>"><?php echo $row['state'];?></option>

                        <option >Select State</option>
                        </select><br/>
```

There were few things which were wrong.

- Option should be inside select box
- select value should be based on database condition

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Thanks Amit but  it is not working for country it is showing as select country only for state is working

Comment: Value is printing in console

Comment: @user5751258 if the value is printing in console then you just need to add if/else in the code to print value as selected or not, and if the $row contains only inserted state/country then its fine.

Comment: iam not getting you what you are saying

Comment: @user5751258 this is example which is similar to your case. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html

Comment: @user5751258 just replace post value with database values, and things would work.

Answer (score 0):

Select box don't contain `value` attribute. You are going by wrong way.

You can use select box by this way:-

```
 <select name="country">
    <option value="country1" <?php if ($row['country'] == 'country1') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>country1</option>
    <option value="country2" <?php if ($row['country'] == 'country2') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>country2</option>
    <option value="country3" <?php if ($row['country'] == 'country3') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>country3</option>
 </select> 

<select name="state">
    <option value="state1" <?php if ($row['state'] == 'state1') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>state1</option>
    <option value="state2" <?php if ($row['state'] == 'state2') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>state2</option>
    <option value="state3" <?php if ($row['state'] == 'state3') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>state3</option>
</select>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign value attribute to Select Box.So you can use Like this:

```
<select name="country">
<option value="country" <?php if ($row['country'] == 'country') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>country</option>
```

```
<select name="state">
<option value="state12" <?php if ($row['state'] == 'state12') { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>state12</option>
```